# Type of data missingness in R

Tags: r, missing-data, generalized-estimating-equations

I am working on a short panel of 3 periods with a few hundred subject, and as the question and as the question suggests, I have some blanks. I know that there are not due to attrition since it is rating data of microfinance institutions and ratings have always been issued (each rating takes 3 years of accounting information, so some info related to past years is not reported).

How can I use R to know whether data is MAR, MCAR or MNAR? I need this info to check whether I can apply GEE to the data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check the sample to discover whether missing data is MCAR, MAR or NMAR because the observed data can't tell you.  You can only really argue on theoretical grounds.

However, since MAR missing observations can be dealt with via imputation you can make NMAR data MAR by adding extra covariates that you think will predict the missing values.  This is almost always a good idea.  (Note that you might only use this extra data in the imputation model, which should contain no more variables than are used in the main analysis).  If the data is truly MCAR then imputations on the assumption of MARness will give an appropriate sense of uncertainty to your main analysis.

On the other hand, if the missingness remains NMAR conditional on everything you know, there's not really any way to discover that.  The only thing to do with the worry is to start adding assumptions and maybe modelling the selection process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This allows me to go forward with more robust methods, since I will argue for the more lax MAR over MCAR.

Comment: I don't understand this. Surely you could test for the distribution of missing values relative to assorted covariates or outcomes the same way you could test for any outcome. If everything is missing for a given subject, you could look to see if the distribution of what remains appears truncated in some unexpected way -- granted that requires some modelling assumptions.

Comment: If you're willing to assume a model for the missing data mechanism, then yes.  Also, if you're willing to assume particular parametric forms, typically measurement model type assumptions that boil down to conditional independence structures, then also yes.  But in general, alas, not.